# C# Equivalent of this powershell snippet

Tags: c#, wmi

I have the below snippet  in PowerShell that is returning me the information I need for local administrators on a remote PC.  I am trying to convert this code into c#, but have been having very little luck with it.

```
 $ADMINS = get-wmiobject -computername $computername -Credential $Credential -query "select * from win32_groupuser where GroupComponent=""Win32_Group.Domain='$computername',Name='administrators'""" | % {$_.partcomponent}
```

I am able to get a basic wmi query working in c# as seen below : 
**Method**

```
 public IEnumerable<CimInstance> WmiQuerier(CimSession session , string wmiquery)
        {

            try
            {
                string Namespace = @"root\cimv2";
                IEnumerable<CimInstance> CimInstances = new List<CimInstance>();
                CimInstances = session.QueryInstances(Namespace, "WQL", wmiquery);
                //IEnumerable<CimInstance> CimInstances2 = CimInstances.SelectMany()
                return CimInstances;
            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                throw;
            }
```

**TEST**

```
   [Test]
        public void CimQuery()
        {
            string querystring = "SELECT * FROM win32_groupuser";
            Wmi wmi = new Wmi();
            NetworkCredential mynetcred = new NetworkCredential("Domain\\User", "Password%");
            CimCredential mycimCred = wmi.ConvertCred(mynetcred);
            CimSession mySession = wmi.WmiConnection(testcomp, mycimCred);
            IEnumerable<CimInstance> querierResults = wmi.WmiQuerier(mySession, querystring).Take(5).ToList();


            Assert.IsInstanceOf<IEnumerable<CimInstance>>(querierResults);
        }
    }
```

However, When I attempt to add in any kind of Where clause like I have in the powershell code, (See my attempt below )

```
"SELECT * FROM win32_groupuser Where GroupComponent = \"Win32_Group.Domain='MachineName',Name='administrators' \""
```

I get the error

> Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimException: 'The WS-Management
>   service cannot process the request. The WQL query is invalid. '

What am I doing incorrectly in my WQL string?

Comment: probably not the reason , but your whitespace is different in the 2 cases

Comment: You could invoke powershell from c# and get the results that way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query that works. I know one thing...that the syntax of the WQL is *extremely* sensitive and unforgiving...especially regarding spaces and quote nesting. Funny enough, it's fine with uppercase/lowercase:

```
using System.Management;

//....


      var domainName = "YourDomainName";
      var groupName = "Administrators";
      var wql = string.Format
      (
        @"select partcomponent from win32_groupuser where groupcomponent='Win32_Group.Domain=""{0}"",Name=""{1}""'",
        domainName,
        groupName
      );
      foreach ( var thing in new ManagementObjectSearcher( wql ).Get( ) )
      {
        foreach ( var property in thing.Properties )
        {
          //--> And then, if you want the account object...
          var path = new ManagementPath( property.Value as string );
          var account = new ManagementObject( path );
          foreach ( var acctProp in account.Properties )
          {
            Console.WriteLine( $"{acctProp.Name}={acctProp.Value}" );
          }
        }
      }
```

**Edit**: Just for yucks, I added code to get the referenced Win32_Account object...since the value of `partcomponent` is a qualified reference to that account object.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear on your example why it is failing since you do not have the `WHERE` clause set. My best guess is that some characters are not being escaped like they should.

You can also use [ORMi](https://github.com/nicoriff/ORMi) library to give your problem an indirect solution. You can do it this way:

```
WMIHelper helper = new WMIHelper("root\\CimV2");

var users = helper.Query("SELECT * FROM Win32_GroupUser").ToList().Where(u => u.Contains("Win32_Group.Domain='MachineName',Name='administrators'"));
```

Comment: You should disclose that you're the author of the library. I've been searching many posts and your comments keep popping up